# Jquery Ajax response as a whole HTML Content

Tags: jsp, jquery

This is my Jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function() {
        var number = $('#number').val();

        $.ajax({
            type:       "post",
            url:        "CALCULATE.JSP",
              dataType: "text",
            success:    function(msg) {

alert(msg);

            }
        });

    return false;
    });
});
```

The issue is that , i am getting the whole HTML content as rsponse instead of a number i am printing on the screen

Please see the output sample here

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=6qjfxe&s=5

Comment: This is a server problem, not an AJAX problem. The server should not be exposing its code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not a jQuery issue, it is an issue with the server setup. It seems the server is not executing the code, but serving it as text instead. You should ask a question on ServerFault and give them details of the server script.

Also, you can test this without the jQuery, by visiting your url (CALCULATE.JSP) from a web browser and view source. You can then see what the server is outputting, when this is corrected, you can move onto testing within jQuery.